# creating a table using associative array

Tags: php, arrays

i want to create a table using an associative key value pair array.
i want its keys as column heading of the table and the values should be in corresponding rows cells. 
array may look like it

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 18270
            [field2] => 24
            [field3] => 7830
            [field4] => 44
            [field5] => 5
            [field6] => 15660
            [field7] => 77
            [field8] => 0
            [field9] => 0
            [field10] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 35070
            [field2] => 24
            [field3] => 15030
            [field4] => 44
            [field5] => 5
            [field6] => 30060
            [field7] => 77
            [field8] => 0
            [field9] => 0
            [field10] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 16051
            [field2] => 24
            [field3] => 6879
            [field4] => 44
            [field5] => 5
            [field6] => 13758
            [field7] => 77
            [field8] => 0
            [field9] => 0
            [field10] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 15050
            [field2] => 24
            [field3] => 6450
            [field4] => 44
            [field5] => 5
            [field6] => 12900
            [field7] => 77
            [field8] => 0
            [field9] => 0
            [field10] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 15750
            [field2] => 24
            [field3] => 6750
            [field4] => 44
            [field5] => 5
            [field6] => 13500
            [field7] => 77
            [field8] => 0
            [field9] => 0
            [field10] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 15750
            [field2] => 24
            [field3] => 6750
            [field4] => 44
            [field5] => 5
            [field6] => 13500
            [field7] => 77
            [field8] => 0
            [field9] => 0
            [field10] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [field1] => 15050
            [field2] => 24
            [field3] => 6450
            [field4] => 44
            [field5] => 5
            [field6] => 12900
            [field7] => 77
            [field8] => 0
            [field9] => 0
            [field10] => 0
        )
)
```

and table should look like this [image: table_image]
i am having problem in creating thead dynamically and putting corresponding values in the columns below it

Comment: What you have tried so far. Post your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
foreach ($table as $rowIndex=>$row) {
  if($rowIndex == 0) {
     echo "<thead><tr>";
     foreach ($row as $columnName=>$cell) {
        if(strpos($columnName, "field") === true) {
           echo "<td>$columnName</td>";
        }
     }
     echo "</tr></thead>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $columnName=>$cell) {
        if(strpos($columnName, "field") === true) {
           echo "<td>$cell</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

more about [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: well it does help.. but i have other key value pairs in that array out of which i want to show just these 10. do u know how do i exclude them.

Comment: in main array or with field1 field2 etc?? just give an example so that we can figure it out. There would be some combination present on which we can filter those keys

Comment: not in main array..  with field1 field2...   ex: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id]=>45
            [name]=>'abc'
            [field1] => 18270
            [field2] => 24
            [field3] => 7830
            [field4] => 44
            [field5] => 5
            [field6] => 15660
            [field7] => 77
            [field8] => 0
            [asddfasd] => 3454
            [field9] => 0
            [field10] => 0
            ['end'] => 
            [field11] => null
        )`

Comment: On the code above, you could try adding this inside the first foreach:

`if ($columnName == 'field11') { break; }`. However you are not helping yourself by showing partial code and letting us guess.

Comment: better to create a temp array of these fields (which you want to use) inside first fooreach loop and then use it in nested foreach

Comment: @Arty2 His fields are not linear so your logic to filter it will not work

Comment: yes they r not linear. plus i want to show only fields which keys having 'field' in it..  so basically i want a logic which print a row value something like only after matching its key value to corresponding column head

Comment: @PritamJinal see updated code. hope it'll solve your problem now and let us know if solved.

Comment: no its not. actually my array structure might not be the same every time so  i need to compare its key to corresponding thead to make sure that right data goes into right cell

Comment: well i got a other way around as a solution.. thanks for helping. your code helps a lot. @kamaldeepsinghbhatia

Answer (score 1):

Though not pretty, the following should do it:

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
foreach (array_name as $row => $columns) {
    if ($row == 0) { //if it's the first row in our dataset
        //first print the table header
        echo '<thead><tr>';
        foreach ($columns as $header => $value) {
            echo '<th>' . $header . '</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr><thead>';
    }
        //then print the data as usual
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($columns as $header => $value) {
            echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

PS: beat to the punch by kamaldeep-singh-bhatia :)